# PHP var in JSON

Tags: php, json, variables

I searched on the internet to see if it was possible to put a php variable in a json text but I found nothing, is it possible? an example below

```
$name = 'Alex';
```

```
{"Hi":"Hi $name!"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array and then convert it to JSON:

```
$array = ['Hi' => "Hi $name!"];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Very helpful, is there a way to put this code directly to my json file?

Comment: No, it has to be in a PHP script to use PHP variables.